# How to resolve error 'You are not allowed to start instance: <instance name>' with openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-swift, openstack-horizon, openstack-neutron

Installed packstack allinone in centos7. when creating vm getting error ' You are not allowed to start instance: '.

Answer (score 0):

that is because of your current privileges and permissions defined in
http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/policy-json-file.html
(yeah, you might be using not Kilo, but different OpenStack release - but that part will be likely same) , 
the one that is relevant here is "compute:start"